# もらえる, 見える rules

Tags: grammar, verbs, potential-form

From what I learned,

> もらえる = もらうことが出来る
> 'can be got'
>
> 見える = 見ることが出来る
> 'can be seen'

This looks like there is some kind of a more general rule for this transformation.

1. If there is a pair of such verbs, is the one with ~え~ always meaning ~ことが出来る?
2. Is there any rule when can I create a ~え~ verb this way?

Comment: 見える does not exactly mean 見ることが　出来る.  There is a difference between 見える and 見られる.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are some ways to get verbs end with える:

1. 五段動詞 can change the last kana to え段 and add る to form a kind of 可能動詞, like:

   > もらう → もらえる 
   >    書く   → 書ける 
   >     飛ぶ  → 飛べる

   They have a similar meaning of the "れる" form : もらわれる　書かれる　飛ばれる. In modern Japanese, the れる form is not so popular as the form of "可能動詞".
2. える is a verb that can be used after the 連用形 of other verbs to show ability or possibility:

   > ある → ありえる 
   >  起こる → 起こりえる

みえる and 聞こえる (I don't know if there are more) are another story, they are from みゆ and きこゆ in classic Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

No to both of your questions. You are mixing up different things.

- `もらえる` is the potential form of the verb `もらう`, and it means the same thing as `もらうことができる`.
- `見える` 'can be seen, is observable' is related to the verb `見る` 'see', but means a different thing. The construction is different from `見ることができる`.

Comment: My teacher introduced もらえる as a simple verb, then I found 見える in a dictionary--so I thought these might be related. Thank you for explaining this.